# Angular2/Webpack: how to load fonts that are imported inside css files?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm using Angular2 beta.15 and webpack 1.12.14.

I have one .css and one .scss file in `app.component.ts` as global patterns like this.

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styles: [
      require('../stylesheets/css/main.min.css'),
      require('../sass/example.scss')
    ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  })
```

And, inside `.css` file, some fonts are imported like below,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
    src: url(fonts/light/helvetica-neue-light.eot) format("eot"), 
         url(fonts/light/helvetica-neue-light.woff2) format("woff2"),   
         url(fonts/light/helvetica-neue-light.woff) format("woff"), 
         url(fonts/light/helvetica-neue-light.ttf) format("truetype");
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal
}
```

In `webpack.config.js`, I have loaders for `.css`, `.scss`, and fonts like below

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
  },
  {
       test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/,
       loader: 'url-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css']
  },
```

When I ran `webpack -display-error-details`, there is no error at all, but when I launched the server to run my app, I got error as below

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Token Promise<ComponentRef>!.
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expected 'styles' to be an array of string
```

If I change the css loader to

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'url-loader'  //or use 'raw-loader'
  },
```

those exceptions disappeared and the app was start, but I got some 404 requests error for those fonts in browser's console, they're not loaded at all.
So, could you give me some pointers? I suspect something wrong in my loader settings.

Comment: Could you try chaining url-loader to raw-loader for the CSS? `['raw-loader', 'url-loader']`

Comment: @SeanLarkin It works! That's great! Could you explain what's usage of `raw-loader`? I can't find a doc for it.

Comment: Yeah I'll create an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you chain multiple loaders together, the order of their actions are completed from right to left.

Then the resulting code from the loader is passed to the next one. In this case, you want to chain the `raw-loader` and `url-loader` like this to give you the desired result:

```
loaders: ['raw-loader', 'url-loader']
```

Since you need to first have your font urls, automatically converted to base64 encoded in the styles, you must first call `url-loader` in your chain. Then since you are looking to import this file as a module.exports, you call `raw-loader`.

So in the chain the following happens:

1. `url-loader`: Converts all of your url references to static assets into `base64:data`.
2. `raw-loader`: Takes your file, and wraps its entire code with a string and then makes it importable by adding `module.exports='string'`

Answer (score 0):

```
        Just Try once to keep under one dir both font and css

        // and give the reference onces in webpack.config.rb

         # Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
         http_path = "/"
         css_dir = "app/assets/css"
         sass_dir = "app/assets/sass"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
styles: [
  require('../stylesheets/css/main.min.css').toString(),
  require('!style-loader!css-loader!less-loader!../less/example.less').toString()
]})
```

I khow the commanand for less, similar command should be available for scss